# How to read the presence of socket connection and host from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sockets, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

For example : 
If I want to read a resource loaded. I can do something like, `window.performance.getEntries()` or `window.performace.getEntriesByType("resource")`. 
And if the third party script has allowed the Timing-Allow-Origin header. I can read the timings and other parameters for the resource.

Now, lets say I want to know the presence of a WebSocket using JavaSscript and NOT by manually moving to "network" tab in chrome devtools and filtering to "WS". Is there any way to do the same.

Comment: What kind of info are you trying to get about your WS connections?

Comment: Presence of a socket and domain/IP to which is listening. @KayceBasques